# drop down list not "dropping down" in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, select, drop-down-menu

I wrote this dropdown list:

```
<div id="select-count">
        <select>
          <option value="canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="france">France</option>
          <option value="india">India</option>
          <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

It works normally in a static html website, but when I put it in wordpress website, it doesn't dropdown anymore. which means that when I click on it, it doesn't show me the choices. 
Is there some kind of compatibility problem that I am missing or something? I am using wordpress 3.7.1.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any errors. Check your CSS.

Comment: Do you have a live example we can look at?

Comment: inspect the element, is it still a drop down or a styled div?

Comment: Thanks for your help! and pete your answer solved the problem. It wasn't a styled div, but you reminded me to inspect the element, and it turned out that the list is hidden by another div, so when I was clicking on the arrow, i was actually clicking on the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, i inspected the element, and it turned out that the list is hidden by another div, so when I was clicking on the arrow, i was actually clicking on the div. so silly..